# C# Accessing Datagrid Event arguments from another Datagrid Event

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have some code which loops through two Datagrids (dgFiles1 and dgFiles2, each one column) and checks for noncommon items in each datagrid. If one item is not in the other, it should highlight the row red.

```
private void dgFiles_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    var itemsSource1 = dgFiles1.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
            var itemsSource2 = dgFiles2.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;

            if (itemsSource1 != null && itemsSource2 != null)
            {
                foreach (var item1 in itemsSource1)
                {
                    bool exists = false;

                    foreach (var item2 in itemsSource2)
                    {
                        if (item1.ToString() == item2.ToString())
                        {
                            colorWhite(dgFiles2, e);
                            exists = true;
                        }
                    }

                    if (!exists)
                    {
                        colorRed(dgFiles1, e);
                    }

                    exists = false;
                }

                foreach (var item1 in itemsSource2)
                {
                    bool exists = false;

                    foreach (var item2 in itemsSource1)
                    {
                        if (item1.ToString() == item2.ToString())
                        {
                            colorWhite(dgFiles1, e);
                            exists = true;
                        }
                    }

                    if (!exists)
                    {
                        colorRed(dgFiles2, e);
                    }

                    exists = false;
                }
            }
}

private void colorWhite(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Background = Brushes.White;
}

private void colorRed(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Background = Brushes.Red;
}
```

dgFiles_LoadingRow is attached to both datagrids LoadingRows events. My problem is that the colorWhite and colorRed functions will only color the rows of the calling datagrid, and never the other datagrid. So say for example the event is triggered by loading some rows into dgFiles1, it will only color the noncommon items red in dgFiles1, and never in dgFiles2 even if it also has noncommon files. I know the logic is working fine, it's just the command to color the other datagrid's rows which isn't working.

I thought that by passing the sender to colorRed or colorWhite, it will color that datagrids rows, but it only does the calling datagrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought that by passing the sender to colorRed or colorWhite, it will color that datagrids rows ...

Then you thought wrong. The `DataGridRowEventArgs` reference is the same throughout the entire method. If the event is raised for a row in `dgFiles1`, you only have a reference to this particular row.

You should be able to get the corresponding container for an item using the `ContainerFromItem` method, e.g.:

```
foreach (var item2 in itemsSource2)
{
    if (item1.ToString() == item2.ToString())
    {
        var row = dgFiles2.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item2) as DataGridRow;
        if(row != null)
            row.Background = Brushes.White;
        exists = true;
    }
}
```